# How to use React Hooks with multiple API calls?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand how to use React Hooks in my new project and I'm looking for some guidance as I didn't find clear answer.

1. I have a form that requires data from 3 separate API calls. Currently I have created 3 hooks like useGetDataSource1, useGetDataSource2 and useGetDataSource3 that wrap API calls with useEffect. Also I've encapsulated usage of these 3 hooks in additional hook called useGetSettings with additional useEffect to separate this logic from form code. Is that correct? Or maybe I should create only one hook useGetSettings and keep data source logic separated in plain JavaScript functions?
2. I want to save data from this form when user presses Submit button. Should I use useCallback for it or I shouldn't use any hook at all? Currently I've created 4 hooks just like with getting data, but without any useEffect/useCallback.

Comment: The advantage of creating custom hooks is to reuse them - are you planning to reuse these in multiple components? If so separate them as it makes sense to you. Otherwise, you do not need to create your own hooks. Just make your api calls in a single `useEffect` or as needed. It really all depends on your use-case.

Comment: Hey there! Please give it a shot and post some code for us to review!

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is meant to control the side effects in functional components, in most cases; you shouldn't need to have a `useEffect` hook inside a hook that encapsulates another hook that uses `useEffect`

Most hooks are meant to `set` and `get`, for example:

`useState` hook can be used like:
`const [count, setCount] = useState(0);`

`count` is the variable you use to `get` the current state value

`setCount` is the `setter`; where you set the state value

Hooks are cool but do not hookify everything, check this article:
[React hooks: not magic, just arrays](https://medium.com/@ryardley/react-hooks-not-magic-just-arrays-cd4f1857236e)

If you'd like to outsource complicated logic to another file and call it a hook; technically you may, but it's best to just call that functional, object oriented programming with separation of concerns, write tiny functions that does one thing, one thing only and does it perfectly, this way; when your code grows, your tiny functions will be easy to maintain with the [power of emergence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16W7c0mb-rE).